# How to obtain JWKs and use them in JWT signing?

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, jwk

I am reading this blog about JWTs and how you can use the signature part of it to verify that the token was actually issued by the trusted party.

https://hackernoon.com/json-web-tokens-jwt-demystified-f7e202249640

> The JSON Web Key (JWK) is a JSON object that contains a well-known public key which can be be used to validate the signature of a signed JWT.
>
> If the issuer of your JWT used an asymmetric key to sign the JWT, it
>   will likely host a file called a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS). The JWKS is
>   a JSON object that contains the property keys, which in turn holds an
>   array of JWK objects.

Here is java code snippet from my codebase that generates JWT for me:

```
new JwtBuilder().setClaims(claims).setExpiration(expiration).signWith(signatureAlgorithm, sharedSecret).compact();
```

I do not quite understand how I obtain JWKs and how do I use them for signing? 
I haven't found any examples on the web.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You download it from the authority that's creating your JWT (usually with something like a `/keys`) endpoint. It looks like you're using symmetric instead of public-key encryption; your `sharedSecret` _is_ the key.

Answer (score 33):

every open id server has to provide the tenant an endpoint like this :

```
  https://--YOUR DOMAIN----/.well-known/jwks.json
```

if you visit this endpoint you will see this in json format

```
{
  keys: [
    {
      alg: 'RS256',
      kty: 'RSA',
      use: 'sig',
      n: 'tTMpnrc4dYlD8MtmPnW3xZNbLxkaGCUwTqeKB4dfLg11dEpMyQEc4JRxUvRzp9tz00r6lkZ1ixcvIiuB_eMVckU8VyFSFWBSAxp5duBk6lRpYk-QjK3kEdPxYLxyW84gNzwMi-XW8zxJbsOa-cRM9sCb62Qz2yfWoQfimoFXsCnVHq496kizO7gZ972JefvTce1_n9dd_1p0K6c14qcCXtF6hbA_gQ0N7h3IyloBqiusKyTsV-ZrMZDldZkI-4v7s49TdcRZgEOvSapMz5YyoDvAWzuWGEiljkjkCOo0Mr5Sioi2x0dBm6nJ2WVYfZrwEF5J',
      e: 'AQAB',
      kid: 'NTY2MjBCNzQ1RTLPQzk3NzczRRTMQ0E4NzE2MjcwOUFCRkUwRTUxNA',
      x5t: 'NTY2MjBCNzQ1RTJPLzk3NzczRUNPO0E4NzE2MjcwOUFCRkUwRTUxNA',
      x5c: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is x5c?

> The "x5c" (X.509 certificate chain which defines how public-key
> certificates must be formatted and used) Header Parameter contains the
> X.509 public key certificate or certificate chain [RFC5280]
> corresponding to the key used to digitally sign the JWS.  The
> certificate or certificate chain is represented as a JSON array of
> certificate value strings.  Each string in the array is a
> base64-encoded (not base64url-encoded) DER [ITU.X690.2008] PKIX
> certificate value.  The certificate containing the public key
> corresponding to the key used to digitally sign the JWS MUST be the
> first certificate.  This MAY be followed by    additional
> certificates, with each subsequent certificate being the one used to
> certify the previous one.  The recipient MUST validatethe certificate
> chain according to RFC 5280 [RFC5280] and consider    the certificate
> or certificate chain to be invalid if any validation    failure
> occurs.  Use of this Header Parameter is OPTIONAL.

if you check the x5c array, you will see very long string. You have to take this value and separate them for each 64 values. it is very simple. here is an example:

```
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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                -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So when you start your verification process:

```
//you get the token
//you decode the token
//you compare the kid which is in the header of the token

//jwk.kid the one that you get when you visit the /.well-known url above
if (jwk.kid === decodedToken.header.kid){
// in verification process you have to use the decoded code and the certificate 
// to verify the signature

}
```

this process is specific to 'RS256' algorithm. RS256 generates an asymmetric signature, which means a private key must be used to sign the JWT and a different public key must be used to verify the signature. Unlike symmetric algorithms, using RS256 offers assurances that Auth0 is the signer of a JWT since Auth0 is the only party with the private key. For verifying the symmetric algorithms, you have to use private key.

Comment: if there is no page at `https://--DOMAIN--/.well-known/jwks.json` (such as Apple and Google),

visit `https://--DOMAIN--/.well-known/openid-configuration` and get from `jwks_uri` key.

Comment: Is it save to have jwks.json hosted publically?

Comment: this is a set of public keys. public keys are ok to share.

Answer (score 2):

With an asymmetric algorithm, within the Authorization Server, a key pair consists of both private and public keys.

- The **private** key remains securely stored within the Authorization Server and is never shared externally; its primary function is to sign JSON Web Tokens (JWTs).
- The **public** key is exposed to the rest of the world via the JWKS endpoint and is used for verifying the JWT signature.

Please see the Java code that uses the public key to sign a JWT, and also extracts a public key out of it and exposes it in JWKS format. The private key in this example is generated by external commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f rs256.key
```

and convert it to a format that Java can use

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in rs256.key -out rs256.pem -nocrypt
```

The following code shows how to use built-in Java utils to deal with asymmetric key signing:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.SignatureException;;

class JwksEndpoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // *******************************
        // Load private key data from file
        // *******************************
        String filePath = "rs256.pem";

        String privateKeyContent;
        try {
            privateKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))) 
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("\n", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // ******************
        // Create private key
        // ******************
        KeyFactory keyFactory;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent)
        );

        PrivateKey privateKey; // Use this key also to sign JWT!
        try {
            privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // *****************
        // Create public key
        // *****************
        RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
            ((RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey).getModulus(),
            ((RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey).getPublicExponent()
        );

        PublicKey publicKey;
        try {
            publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
            
        // *********************
        // Prepare JWKS response
        // *********************
        RSAPublicKey rsa = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;

        String jwksResponse = String.format(
            """
            {
                keys: [{
                    "kty": "%s",
                    "kid": "1",
                    "n": "%s",
                    "e": "%s",
                    "alg": "RS256",
                    "use": "sig"
                }]
            }
            """,
            rsa.getAlgorithm(),
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.getModulus().toByteArray()),
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.getPublicExponent().toByteArray())
        );

        System.out.println(jwksResponse);

        // *******************
        // Example JWT signing
        // *******************
        String jwtHeader = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
            """
            { "alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT", "kid": "1" }
            """.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

        );

        String jwtPayloadTemplate = """
            {
                "sub": "luke.schwember",
                "iss": "https://luke10x.dev",
                "iat": %s,
                "exp": %s,
                "aud": "My-Audience"
            }
            """.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "");

        String jwtPayload = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
            String.format(
                jwtPayloadTemplate,
                Instant.now().getEpochSecond(),
                Instant.now().plusSeconds(300).getEpochSecond()
            ).replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        );

        String jwtContent = jwtHeader + "." + jwtPayload;

        Signature signature;

        try {
            signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String jwtSignature;
        try {
            signature.update(jwtContent.getBytes());
            jwtSignature = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                signature.sign()
            );
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String jwt = jwtContent + "." + jwtSignature;
        System.out.println(jwt);
    }
}
```

Feel free to organize this code in your Authorization Server using the same key to sign JWT upon user login, and to expose the JWKS endpoint.

In Resource Server, however, to perform key validation of JWT, my advice is to use some library of the framework, as this is critical for your application security and it is better to use a well-tested solution.

For example to implement a Resource Server with Spring Boot Security one can use `@Configuration` drop-in like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
          .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
              .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwkSetUri(YOUR_JWKS_ENDPOINT_URL_IN_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER))
          ); 
          
      return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I looked exactly for this, when implementing my oidc server (playing with stuff), underrated answer