# How to produce correct jwks endpoint for spring oauth2 jwt server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

### The Issued Goal

To configure `/.well-known/jwks.json` for my spring oauth2 jwt server with valid `jwks`.

### 1st Attempt

Following [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-authorization-server-spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-jwk-set-uri) I can use out the box Endpoint for JWK Set URI. It requires:

```
@Import(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class)
```

I've added. Checking mapped endpoints via actuator nothing filtered for `jw`.

### 2nd Attempt

Following the same configuration I tried to use next code:

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
...

@FrameworkEndpoint
class JwkSetEndpoint {
    KeyPair keyPair;

    public JwkSetEndpoint(KeyPair keyPair) {
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
    }

    @GetMapping("/.well-known/jwks.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getKey(Principal principal) {
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) this.keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).build();
        return new JWKSet(key).toJSONObject();
    }
}
```

It produces

```
{
  "keys" : [ {
    "kty" : "RSA",
    "e" : "AQAB",
    "n" : "mWI2jtKwvf0W1hdMdajch-mFx9FZe3CZnKNvT_d0-2O6V1Pgkz7L2FcQx2uoV7gHgk5mmb2MZUsy_rDKj0dMfLzyXqBcCRxD6avALwu8AAiGRxe2dl8HqIHyo7P4R1nUaea1WCZB_i7AxZNAQtcCcSvMvF2t33p3vYXY6SqMucMD4yHOTXexoWhzwRqjyyC8I8uCYJ-xIfQvaK9Q1RzKRj99IRa1qyNgdeHjkwW9v2Fd4O_Ln1Tzfnk_dMLqxaNsXPw37nw-OUhycFDPPQF_H4Q4-UDJ3ATf5Z2yQKkUQlD45OO2mIXjkWprAmOCi76dLB2yzhCX_plGJwcgb8XHEQ"
  } ]
}
```

Pinging resource server with access_token is failed:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid JWT/JWS: kid is a required JOSE Header"}
```

### 3rd Attempt

Modifying response for `"/.well-known/jwks.json"` (`jwt.io helps detect algorithm used for jwt`):

```
        RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .keyID("1")
                .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
                .algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.RS256)
                .build();
```

leads to next response:

```
{
  "keys" : [ {
    "kty" : "RSA",
    "e" : "AQAB",
    "use" : "sig",
    "kid" : "1",
    "alg" : "RS256",
    "n" : "mWI2jtKwvf0W1hdMdajch-mFx9FZe3CZnKNvT_d0-2O6V1Pgkz7L2FcQx2uoV7gHgk5mmb2MZUsy_rDKj0dMfLzyXqBcCRxD6avALwu8AAiGRxe2dl8HqIHyo7P4R1nUaea1WCZB_i7AxZNAQtcCcSvMvF2t33p3vYXY6SqMucMD4yHOTXexoWhzwRqjyyC8I8uCYJ-xIfQvaK9Q1RzKRj99IRa1qyNgdeHjkwW9v2Fd4O_Ln1Tzfnk_dMLqxaNsXPw37nw-OUhycFDPPQF_H4Q4-UDJ3ATf5Z2yQKkUQlD45OO2mIXjkWprAmOCi76dLB2yzhCX_plGJwcgb8XHEQ"
  } ]
}
```

Pinging resource server with access_token provides the same result:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid JWT/JWS: kid is a required JOSE Header"}
```

### Question

Is any ideas or examples how to configure `/.well-known/jwks.json` to produce correct `jwks`?

### P.S.

- In case I use public key as local resource on the resource server - it works.
- I'll be happy to any working solution (possible someone knows different `jwks` libraries that can be used in spring-boot application).

Comment: Another similar thread [Creating jwks endpoint spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930625/creating-jwks-endpoint-spring-boot) seemingly uses [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) library.

Answer (score 1):

Any update to this?

We are looking into signature based authentication, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-12,

One of the requirements will be to implement the /.well-known/jwks.json endpoint so we don't have to have a separate public key distribution mechanism.

I haven't yet done this but it looks like:

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    return JWKSet.load(keyStore, (name) -> null).toPublicJWKSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate JWKS endpoint you could use some good library like nimbus-jose-jwt, but it is also possible to do it with **no external libraries** at all.

For that you need to generate the key file:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f rs256.key
```

and convert to what Java can work with:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in rs256.key -out rs256.pem -nocrypt
```

The JWKS endpoint response then can be generated with the following code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

class JwksEndpoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // *******************************
        // Load private key data from file
        // *******************************
        String filePath = "rs256.pem";

        String privateKeyContent;
        try {
            privateKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))) 
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("\n", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // ******************
        // Create private key
        // ******************
        KeyFactory keyFactory;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent)
        );
        PrivateKey privateKey; // Use this key also to sign JWT!
        try {
            privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // *****************
        // Create public key
        // *****************
        RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
            ((RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey).getModulus(),
            ((RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey).getPublicExponent()
        );

        PublicKey publicKey;
        try {
            publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
            
        // *********************
        // Prepare JWKS response
        // *********************
        RSAPublicKey rsa = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;

        Map<String, Object> keyObject = new HashMap<>();
        keyObject.put("kty", rsa.getAlgorithm());
        keyObject.put("kid", "1");
        keyObject.put(
            "n",
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.getModulus().toByteArray())
        );
        keyObject.put(
            "e",
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.getPublicExponent().toByteArray())
        );
        keyObject.put("alg", "RS256");
        keyObject.put("use", "sig");

        List<Map<String, Object>> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
        keyList.add(keyObject);

        Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> jwksResponse = new HashMap<>();
        jwksResponse.put("keys", keyList);

        System.out.println(jwksResponse);
    }
}
```

You probably need some library like `org.json` or Jackson to serialize the JWKS data to JSON unless you want to use StringBuilder. Still, the generation of JWKS itself does not need any external libraries.

Comment: My answer to "[How to obtain JWKs and use them in JWT signing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77676615/296988)" has a more complete code example also showing how to sign a JWT using the private key.